# Filter to change boolean value to string - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I need to make one filter in angularjs app. In my database, I keep a string value to say if the data is ative or inative. I use 'S' to active and 'N' to inative. But I made a checkbox button in my page to filter the data returned of the database, to show inatives or not. But I need to convert the value returned of de checkbox button to 'S' or 'N'. How can I do it? I am trying using this code:

```
app.filter('cakeActive', function(){
return function(input){
    if(input == true){
        return 'S';
    }
    else {
        return 'N';
    }
};
```

});

And in my DOM, is this:

```
<input checked type="checkbox" ng-model="active">
        <div class="col s12 m12 l12" ng-repeat="cake in cakes | {cake.active == cakeActive:active}">...</div>
```

This is not working. What the best form to fix this situation?
Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you fix the root problem and add proper types to your DB model?

Comment: You tried active|cakeActive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [ng-true-value, ng-false-value](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D) for that.